# Call bash script after exiting python program

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm new to Python and have been able to find answers to most of my questions here so I thought you guys could help me with this one:

I'm developing somewhat of a hybrid application using bash scripts to show menus and to call python applications (I'm doing it this way to simplify things).

My problem is that when I end the python application, it simply terminates the process and to go back to the menus, I have to start the whole program again. I tried using "subprocess.call('xxx')" but it opens the bash scrips inside of the application I am running and shows text (echo) only, no other functions.

Is there a way to end the python application first and then call the shell script?

Comment: "When I end the python application, it simply terminates the process and to go back to the menus, I have to start the whole program again." What you should do is embed the call to the python program in a loop (in your bash script). Also, why can't you just code the menu in Python?

Comment: @4ae1e1 yes, that worked like a charm! Thank you! :) And to be honest, because I had already made all of them using bash and converting it to python would've taken a lot of time... I'm only using python for database operations, everything else on the "application" is bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in a while-true loop

```
while :; do
    # Assuming you want to show the menu before you start a program:
    bash showMenu.py
    python myScript.py
    # When the above scripts exits the process will start all over again
    # You might want to consider checking the exit code and only continue if the program exits with status code 0
    # [ $? gt 0 ] && break
done
```

Comment: I actually used "wait" in my bash script as suggested by 4ae1e1, because it seemed easier to do it this way... But thank you for your answer! :-)

Comment: I didn't suggest wait anywhere in my comment... My answer would have been the same as this one.

Comment: @4ae1e1 You  will need to use `@user` to inform John about your comment :-) If you dont it will go to the OP of the post (me in this case)